# gpg commands to extract key information inside python script

Tags: python, gnupg

I have a python script to check for gpg public key and gpg private keys expiration. So far I was managed to get the keys expiration information using gpg commands inside os.system('gpg ...') commands.

This works fine for both public and private keys but when I run that python script from nrpe server the gpg command unable to get the private key information

Public key:

```
os.system('gpg -n key.gpg > key_info.txt')
```

Private key:

```
os.system('gpg --batch --import key.gpg > /dev/null 2>&1')
os.system('gpg --list-secret-keys > key_info.txt')
```

Is there any way to get the private key information using any other commands.

Also any way to use gnupg module to get the keys information, I see we can use gnup module only to do some operations such as encrypt/decrypt etc.

Comment: Using gnupg to get the key is relatively simple, however if you're having authentication issues on the server then you still won't be able to get the private key info. What error message(s) are you getting?

Comment: I dont see any error. I see the key_info.txt file was created and its empty. The public key command is running successfully but whereas the private key command is failing with empty output.

Comment: Can you run `gpg --batch --import key.gpg` on the server and post any error messages? Not the whole output, just any errors. This part: `> /dev/null 2>&1` of that command hides both the output and errors from the command - which is fine for the script but probably why you aren't seeing an error.

Comment: I tried removing `> /dev/null 2>&` this part but still I didnt see any error. Was able to make it work with the below answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to run the script and get the private key information from another nrpe server using this gpg command

```
gpg -n --with-fingerprint --keyid-format=long --show-keys keys.gpg > keys_info.txt
```